# Stray end tag "tr" and 1 column wide errors

Tags: html

Just starting some HTML5 scripting for my assignment at school. I'm done writing it, however I am encountering 2 errors when submitting my file to http://validator.w3.org/

1. A table row was 1 columns wide, which is less than the column count established by the first row (6).
2. Stray end tag tr.

I also have another error for the border of my table, but my prof said to ignore that error. I am trying to produce the following: https://postimg.org/image/ruv1y0vb1/

I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <title> Assignment 1: Question 2 </title>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3> Assignment #1/Question 2 </h3>
        <table border = "1">
            <tr>
                <td colspan = "6"> <h1> Some Canadian Provinces </h1> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan = "7"> 
                    <img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/c/cf/Flag_of_Canada.svg/1280px-Flag_of_Canada.svg.png"
                        alt = "Canadian Flag" width = "200" height = "100">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th> Province </th>
                <td> Quebec </td>
                <td> Ontario </td>
                <td> British Columbia </td>
                <td> Alberta </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th> Flag </th>
                <td> 
                    <img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5f/Flag_of_Quebec.svg/600px-Flag_of_Quebec.svg.png"
                            alt = "Quebec Flag" width = "100" height = "55">
                </td>
                <td> 
                    <img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/88/Flag_of_Ontario.svg/1280px-Flag_of_Ontario.svg.png"
                            alt = "Ontario Flag" width = "100" height = "55">
                </td>
                <td> 
                    <img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b8/Flag_of_British_Columbia.svg/600px-Flag_of_British_Columbia.svg.png"
                            alt = "British Columbia Flag" width = "110" height = "55">
                </td>
                <td> 
                    <img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f5/Flag_of_Alberta.svg/1000px-Flag_of_Alberta.svg.png"
                            alt = "Alberta Flag" width = "100" height = "55" >
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th> Capital </th>
                <td> Quebec City </td>
                <td> Toronto </td>
                <td> Victoria </td>
                <td> Edmonton </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th> Postal Abbreviation </th>
                <td> QC </td>
                <td> ON </td>
                <td> BC </td>
                <td> AB </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th> Year Entered<br/>Confederation </th>
                <td> 1867 </td>
                <td> 1867 </td>
                <td> 1871 </td>
                <td> 1905 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan = "5"> <strong>References and flags: </strong>
                    <a href = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec"> Quebec</a> &nbsp;
                    <a href = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontario"> Ontario</a> &nbsp;
                    <a href = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Columbia"> British Columbia</a> &nbsp;
                    <a href = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alberta"> Alberta</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check last few lines of your HTML... two closing </tr> tags...remove one. After that fix, few errors are left... And yes, you can remove border attribute - use css for styling...

Comment: I can't seem to figure it out. I don't understand what's going on. It seems like a simple problem to fix, but I just don't see it. I removed the </tr> tag, so that's fixed. It still tells me that the table row was 1 column wide. Which table row is it? I've tried modifying everything and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm getting the same error no matter what I do.

Comment: Check second answer - it could lead you to solution....

Answer (score 0):

You only have one  element, but looking at your indentation there are two nested levels of .  Fix the indentation and the stray  will make itself obvious.

Comment: I checked the formatting and made some changes on the indentation. Ran  through the whole code, still can't spot it.

Answer (score 0):

Some comments based on the code you posted:
 You have mixed up tr and td tags.  You need to create another table inside the td tag and then have the rest of the code inside that tag.  Never mix tags.

```html
<table border = "1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan = "6"> <h1> Some Canadian Provinces </h1> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan = "7"> 
    </td>
  <!--You need to create a td tag here and add another table -->
    <td>
    <table>
      <tr>
         <th> Province </th>
         <td> Quebec </td>
         <td> Ontario </td>
         <td> British Columbia </td>
         <td> Alberta </td>
     </tr>
     .
     .
     .
   </table>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Thereafter check the colspan and rowspan properties, and adjust accordingly.

Comment: This is creating a table inside a table, but I don't wish to accomplish that.

Comment: I've tried it but it gives me more errors than before